# Options for developing with Adobe Commerce / Gift Cards

Tags: magento2-enterprise, gift-card, adobe-commerce

I would like to *proof of concept* an application which uses Adobe Commerce's (Magento Enterprise) Gift Card module via its API.

I'm struggling to figure out what my options are for testing against an Adobe Commerce installation to do this (either on-premise or cloud, whatever works!). As far as I can tell I can get a sandbox set up with **Silver** Technology Partner membership, but I would also have to commit to submitting an official extension to the marketplace.

Am I missing anything? Can anyone help understand what my options are for developing against Adobe Commerce APIs? Or is there any way to test the Gift Card module using the standard OS Magento?